Prove De Brujin graph can be partitioned to cycles.
I'm trying to prove that in a De Bruijn graph $G_{σ,n}$ a set of simple cycles can be found such that the length of each cycle divides $n-1$ and that each vertex appears in only one cycle. Can someone give me a hint? Is the fact that the graph has an Euler cycle a good start?
Edit: more details: σ=|Σ| - size of alphabet, and n is length of strings that represent edges, vertices are strings of length n-1

What do $\sigma$ and $n$ stand for in your definition of the De Bruijn graph $G_{\sigma,n}$?

σ=|Σ| - size of alphabet, and n is length of strings that represent edges, vertices are strings of length n-1

please edit the question to include the info in your comment. comments can be deleted and the question should be standing on its own.

Let $\Sigma$ denote the alphabet so that the vertex set of $G_{\sigma,n}$ is $\Sigma^{n-1}$. Let $\varphi:\Sigma^{n-1} \to \Sigma^{n-1}$ be given by
$$\varphi(v_1v_2\cdots v_{n-1}) = v_2 \cdots v_{n-1}v_1.$$
Observe that $\varphi^{n-1}$ is the identity function. Pick any word $w \in \Sigma^{n-1}$. We get a closed directed walk
$$w \to \varphi(w) \to \varphi^2(w) \to \cdots \to \varphi^{n-1}(w) = w.$$
Let $k$ be the smallest positive power for which $\varphi^k(w) = w$. Then

$w \to \varphi(w) \to \cdots \to \varphi^k(w) = w$ is a directed cycle,
$w,\varphi(w),...,\varphi^{k-1}(w)$ all generate the same cycle, and
$\varphi^\ell(w) = w$ if and only if $\ell$ is a multiple of $k$.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the set (not multiset!) of these cycles generated by $\varphi$ and words $w \in \Sigma^{n-1}$. 1. guarantees every word is contained in some cycle. 2. ensures that the cycles in $\mathcal{C}$ are vertex disjoint. And 3. shows that the length of each cycle divides $n-1$.

Thank you!!!!!!
